# ¿Cómo pasar un JSON como parámetro en un Form al controlador?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net, mvc

Tengo esta clase:

```
public class Comprobante
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
   public Guid IdComprobante { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el Contacto")]
    [Column("IdContacto")]
   public virtual Contacto Contacto { get; set; }
    [Column("IdContacto")]
    public virtual Contacto Socio { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el Tipo de Comprobante")]
   public virtual TipoDeComprobante ComprobanteTipo { get; set; }
    /*[Required]*/
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el Numero de Sucursal")]
    [Range(0, 9999)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,4:0000}")]
    public int Sucursal { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el Numero de Comprobante")]
    [Range(0, 99999999)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,8:00000000}")]
   public int Numero { get; set; }
    [Column("IditemComprobante")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Comprobante_Detalle> Productos { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
   public string Observaciones { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el Total del Comprobante")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "$ {0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
   public decimal Total { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "$ {0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
   public decimal Pagado { get; set; }
    [Required]
   public bool Saldado { get; set; } = false;
    [Required]
   public DateTime UltimaActualización { get; set; }
}
```

Antes de entrar en la vista creo el objeto y lo lleno con algunos parámetros:

```
public IActionResult GenerarComprobante(Guid id)
{
    Comprobante comp = new Comprobante();
    TipoDeComprobante tcomp = _context.TipoDeComprobante.Where(c => c.Tipo == "COMP").FirstOrDefault();
    if (tcomp == null) {
        _context.TipoDeComprobante.Add(new TipoDeComprobante
        {
            NumeroSiguiente = 1,
            UltimaActualización = DateTime.Now,
            Descripción = "Comprobante",
            Tipo = "COMP"
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();
        tcomp = _context.TipoDeComprobante.Where(c => c.Tipo == "COMP").FirstOrDefault();
    }
    comp.IdComprobante = Guid.NewGuid();
    comp.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
    comp.Contacto = _context.Contacto.Where(c => c.IdContacto == id).FirstOrDefault();
    comp.ComprobanteTipo = tcomp;
    comp.Numero = tcomp.NumeroSiguiente;
    comp.Sucursal = 0;
    comp.Total = 0;
    comp.Pagado = 0;
    comp.Saldado = false;
    comp.Socio = null;
    comp.Productos = null;
    ViewBag.Comprobante = comp;
    return View(comp);
}
```

Lo recibo en la vista y se lo paso a una variable en *JavaScript*:

```
var jsonComprobante = JSON.parse(
  '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model))'
);
```

Con *JavaScript* lo lleno y luego se lo quiero pasar a otro controlador y guardarlo en la base de datos pero no quiero usar *AJAX*.

Ahora estoy haciendo esto:

```
function guardarComprobante() {
    console.log("Comp: " + JSON.stringify(jsonComprobante));
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("respuesta: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', '/Comprobantes/Guardar');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("jsonComprobante=" + JSON.stringify(jsonComprobante));
}
```

¿Es posible pasarlo como un parámetro en un formulario?

¿Cómo puedo pasarlo a un `input` o algo parecido? Seguramente en un `input` estoy limitando el tamaño.

¿Cuál seria la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Agrega el codigo de tu objeto, y como lo usarias en el controlador.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, e indica el código que has hecho.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: jaja, perdón! voy a mejorar. reformulo la pregunta...

Comment: ahora esta bien desarrollada la pregunta? gracias por su tiempo!